# How do I fill in a circle made by ParametricPlot with one solid color?

Tags: plotting, color

I have a very simple question but I am new with *Mathematica*. 
I made a circle on a parametric plot and I made the line black.
I want to make the inside of the circle on the parametric plot red. So the result should be a red-filled circle with a black outline on an x and y axis.

Code:

```
ParametricPlot[{Cos[u], Sin[u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Black]
```

Comment: You were asking about `ParametricPlot[]`, but I presume you are aware of the `Circle[]` and `Disk[]` primitives?

Answer (score 16):

One simple way to go about it:

```
ParametricPlot[{Cos[u], Sin[u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}] /.
  Line[l_List] :> {{Red, Polygon[l]}, {Black, Line[l]}}
```

[image: filled circle]

If you want the border to be a tad more prominent:

```
ParametricPlot[{Cos[u], Sin[u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}] /. 
  Line[l_List] :> {{Red, Polygon[l]}, {Directive[AbsoluteThickness[3], Black], Line[l]}}
```

[image: filled circle with thicker border]

An alternative would be

```
ParametricPlot[{Cos[u], Sin[u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}] /. 
  l_Line :> {EdgeForm[Directive[AbsoluteThickness[3], Black]], Red, FilledCurve[l]}
```

---

(after some prompting by Sjoerd)

All three snippets act by replacing any `Line[]` object produced by `ParametricPlot[]`, via `ReplaceAll[]` (`/.`) and `RuleDelayed[]` (`:>`). With the first two, the instruction reads as "replace any `Line[]`s present with a `Red` `Polygon[]` (for filling the inside) and a `Black` `Line[]` (with a thickening through `AbsoluteThickness[]` in the second version)", the `Polygon[]` object coming first in the right-hand side of the `RuleDelayed[]` so that it is rendered first before the `Line[]`.

The third version makes use of the `FilledCurve[]` primitive, which is new in version eight. `EdgeForm[]` is used to make the edges of the `FilledCurve[]` object black and thick, and `Red` colors the filling red.

Comment: Nice point! But it didn't works on `With[{n = 5},
 ParametricPlot[{Sin[n u] Cos[u], Sin[n u] Sin[u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}] /. 
  Line[l_List] :> {{Red, Polygon[l]}, {Black, Line[l]}}]`
 if OddQ n.

Comment: @chyanog, that's because your curve is self-intersecting. The solution presented here won't work for that case.

Comment: The filled color is a bit transparent. Anyway to change that?

Comment: @ablmf, please try adding `BaseStyle -> Opacity[1]` and report back.

Comment: @J.M. It doesn't seem to work, but @ablmf, it is enough to replace `Red` with `Directive[Red,Opacity[1]]`.

Comment: @Druid, it worked in older versions; perhaps things have changed since then.

Answer (score 6):

What about

```
ListLinePlot[Table[{Cos[u], Sin[u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi, .05}], 
PlotStyle -> {Thick, Black}, Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> Red, 
AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> None, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

If you insist on `ParametricPlot`

```
Show[ParametricPlot[{{r Cos[u], r Sin[u]}}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {r, 0, 1}, 
PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", Mesh -> 0, 
ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, u, v}, Red], 
ColorFunctionScaling -> False, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
Exclusions -> {Cos[u] == 1}, Axes -> False, ExclusionsStyle -> Red],
ParametricPlot[{{ Cos[u], Sin[u]}}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, 
PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.01]], Axes -> False]]
```

[image]

Comment: It's a tad simpler to do `ColorFunction -> (Red &)`...

Comment: @J.M. I copied directly from the Doc.. As I grow older my brain is behaving more like the Nokia stock..

Comment: Note the use of `ColorFunction` is disabling anti-aliasing.

Comment: @ChrisDegnen is there a way to keep the anti-aliasing ok while using `ColorFunction`...

Comment: I couldn't find a way.  The examples on `RegionPlot` that use `ColorFunction` don't have anti-aliasing either, at least on 7.0.1.

Answer (score 6):

Two-parameter `ParametricPlot` with `Exclusions`:

```
 ParametricPlot[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {r, 0, 1}, 
 Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Opacity[1]],
 Exclusions -> {r == 1},
 ExclusionsStyle -> Directive[EdgeForm[{AbsoluteThickness[3], Black}]],
 BoundaryStyle -> None, (* thanks to J.M.'s comment *)
 PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe include `BoundaryStyle -> None` to get rid of that blue line covering up the positive $x$-axis?

Comment: @J.M. Thank you; didn't even notice till your comment -- now I "see". `AxesStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[15]` also works:)

Answer (score 3):

Using `Show` with a parametric region plot and a parametric curve plot:

```
Show[
 ParametricPlot[v {Cos[u], Sin[u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 1},
  Mesh -> False, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Opacity[1]],
  BoundaryStyle -> None],
 ParametricPlot[{Cos[u], Sin[u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi},
  PlotStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[8], Black}],
 Frame -> False, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 240]
```

[image]

Comment: I was about to suggest using `BoundaryStyle -> Black`, but then thought to try to remove the axes first... there's a radius cutting into the circle. Maybe include `BoundaryStyle -> None` in the options?

Comment: `PlotStyle->Directive[Opacity[1],Red]` gets rid of the default opacity (`Opacity[0.2]`).

Answer (score 2):

Great question.  Too bad I missed it until today.  Anyway, after viewing the existing solutions I think have something to offer.  It is a variation of [Chris Degnen](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/363/chris-degnen)'s method, but I control `Mesh` instead of using a second plot and give a simpler form for `PlotStyle`.

```
ParametricPlot[v {Cos[u], Sin[u]}, {u, 0, 2.1 Pi}, {v, 0, 1},
 Mesh -> {0, {1}},
 MeshStyle -> Thick,
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[1, Red],
 BoundaryStyle -> None,
 Axes -> None
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using `Cases` to extract plot data:

```
ParametricPlot[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}] //
  Cases[#, Line[x_] -> x, Infinity] & //
 Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Black, Thick}], Red, Polygon[First@#]}, Axes -> 1] &
```