# Filling between parametric plots

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

I am new with Mathematica, but am trying to fill an area between two parametric plots

```
ParametricPlot[{{u + Sin[u], -Cos[u]}, {u + Sin[u + Pi], Cos[u + Pi]}}, 
{u, 0, Pi}, Axes -> True ]
```

which thus far are nice, clean curves:

[image: 1]

Thanks to the answers here: [How do I fill in a circle made by ParametricPlot with one solid color?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-fill-in-a-circle-made-by-parametricplot-with-one-solid-color) I became aware of `ListLinePlot`.

However, my `ListLinePlot` for this situation

```
ListLinePlot[Table[{{u + Sin[u], -Cos[u]}, {u + Sin[u + Pi], Cos[u + Pi]}},
{u, 0, Pi, 0.0005}], Mesh -> All, 
MeshStyle -> Directive[AbsolutePointSize[0.0005], Black], 
PlotStyle -> Directive[Thin, LightGray]]
```

[image: 2]

does not seem to give as good a resolution no matter how finely I subdivide the interval, and also produces problems with self-intersection near the boundaries when plotting several periods. In particular, the contrast with similar curves filled in `Plot` is striking.

Is there a smarter way to fill the area between these parametric curves? Perhaps using something else than `ListLinePlot`? Thanks!

Comment: Don't accept my answer all too quickly! I am sure there are other approaches, give them a chance too :) (by the way: welcome to mathematica.se, great way to present a first question!)

Comment: Thanks for the welcome, and the helpful answer. Using `ParametricPlot` in the way you suggest gives me full resolution, without the somewhat artificial contrivance of `ListLinePlot` drawing vertical lines between the two data sets to fill the area. I have tentatively "unaccepted" to allow other people to give their input, but hope to reverse that soon :).

Comment: Great! Note that you got the vertical lines as you missed to `Transpose` your data in `ListLinePlot`, thus it connected 2 points of each curve instead of the points on the curve. See `ListLinePlot` docu. I also added more info in my answer (and don't forget, you can still upvote :) )

Comment: Related: [(5087)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5087/121)

Comment: Your own "filling" solution using ListLinePlot is quite ingenious IMHO. :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**`ParametricPlot`**

Here's a way that seems to work **in your case** (see below in @ssch's (thanks!) comments when it doesn't)

Let (for better readability)

```
f1[u_] := {u + Sin[u], -Cos[u]}
f2[u_] := {u + Sin[u + Pi], Cos[u + Pi]}
```

And then

```
ParametricPlot[{ v f1[u] + (1 - v) f2[u]}, {u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0, 1}, 
   Axes -> True, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> LightGray]
```

i.e., we just add an auxiliary parameter `v`, to "shift" between the curves.

[image]

Using `ColorFunction`, you can add more colors:

```
ParametricPlot[{v f1[u] + (1 - v) f2[u]}, {u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0, 1}, 
  Axes -> True, Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, u, v}, Hue[v]]]
```

(I won't paste a picture of that here)

---

**`ListLinePlot`**

For `ListLinePlot`, note that your data is wrongly formatted, try e.g.:

```
ListLinePlot[
   Transpose@Table[{{u + Sin[u], -Cos[u]}, {u + Sin[u + Pi], Cos[u + Pi]}}, 
      {u, 0, Pi, 0.01}], Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
```

Note the `Transpose` I added to fix the issue.

Comment: Visualization of the `ParametricPlot` procedure: `Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[{
   v f1[u] + (1 - v) f2[u],
   f1[u], f2[u]}, {u, 0, Pi},
  Epilog -> {
    Point[{f1[û], f2[û]}],
    Line[{f1[û], f2[û]}]}]
 , {{v, .5}, 0, 1}
 , {{û, 2.}, 0, Pi}]`

Comment: More instructive when it fails: `f1[u_] := {u + Sin[u], -Cos[u]};
f2[u_] := {u + Sin[u + Pi], Cos[2 (u - Pi/2) + Pi]};
pp = ParametricPlot[{v f1[u] + (1 - v) f2[u]}, {u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0, 1}, 
   Mesh -> None];
Manipulate[
 Show[
  pp,
  Epilog -> {Line[{f1[u], f2[u]}]}
  ],
 {{u, 0.5}, 0, Pi}]`

Comment: I guess I have to put "in your case" in bold... thanks for pointing that out explicitly, thanks @ssch

Comment: How would you do it if instead of two curves there were several that form a closed loop ?

Answer (score 10):

Similar to @ybeltukov, you can extract the lines from the plot.  But to get a proper polygon, you need to reverse one of the lines.

```
plot = ParametricPlot[{{u + Sin[u], -Cos[u]}, {u + Sin[u + Pi], 
     Cos[u + Pi]}}, {u, 0, Pi}, Axes -> True];
{line1, line2} = Cases[plot, l_Line :> First@l, Infinity];

Graphics[
 {Opacity[0.4], Darker@Blue, EdgeForm[Darker@Blue], 
  Polygon[Join[line1, Reverse@line2]]},
 Options[plot]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then one can style the polygon and/or lines as desired.

```
Graphics[
 {{Opacity[0.4], ColorData[1][3], 
   Polygon[Join[line1, Reverse@line2]]}, Thick, ColorData[1][1], 
  Line@line1, ColorData[1][2], Line@line2},
 Options[plot]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 8):

A subtly different ListLinePlot approach:

```
ListLinePlot[{
      Table[{u + Sin[u], -Cos[u]}, {u, 0, Pi, 0.005}],
      Table[{u + Sin[u + Pi], Cos[u + Pi]}, {u, 0, Pi, 0.005}]},
          Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, LightGray}}, PlotStyle -> Black]
```

It looks better to me in terms of jaggies:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I think this addresses the issue pointed out by Pinguin Dirk in the comments as well as in his answer: my `ListLinePlot` data needs to be transposed - the resolution problems stem from this.

Comment: This is the same way I thought of. +1

Answer (score 6):

I think you can use `Piecewise` and the approach in your link [How do I fill in a circle made by ParametricPlot with one solid color?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-fill-in-a-circle-made-by-parametricplot-with-one-solid-color)

```
ParametricPlot[
 {Piecewise[{{u + Sin[u], u < Pi}, {u - Pi + Sin[u], u > Pi}}], 
  Piecewise[{{-Cos[u], u < Pi}, {Cos[u], u > Pi}}]}, 
 {u, 0, 2 Pi}, Axes -> True] /. Line[l_List] :> {{Red, Polygon[l]}, {Black, Line[l]}}
```

[image: parametric plot]

Answer (score 3):

Use separate table for each curve or transpose the table, then use filling.

```
ListLinePlot[
 Table[#, {u, 0, Pi, Pi/100}] & /@  {{u + Sin[u], -Cos[u]},
                                     {u + Sin[u + Pi], Cos[u + Pi]}},
 Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, FillingStyle -> GrayLevel[.95]];

ListLinePlot[
 Transpose[Table[{{u + Sin[u], -Cos[u]}, {u + Sin[u + Pi], Cos[u + Pi]}},
                 {u, 0, Pi, Pi/100}]],
 Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, FillingStyle -> GrayLevel[.95]]
```

[image]

Comment: This is what george2079 did in an answer before yours.

Answer (score 0):

I tried just :

```
ListLinePlot[
 Table[#, {u, 0, Pi, Pi/100}] & /@  {{u + Sin[u], -Cos[u]},
                                 {u + Sin[u + Pi], Cos[u + Pi]}},
 Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, FillingStyle -> Green[.95]];
```

And it made the same figure but the color of filling is blue between the curves. So why do you need the transpose version also?