# Filling between ParametricPlot and Plot

Tags: plotting, color, parametric-functions, filling

There are some similar questions: [(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-fill-in-a-circle-made-by-parametricplot-with-one-solid-color) [(2)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31659/filling-between-parametric-plots) have been ask, but I think this is a different one.

If we have a `ParametricPlot` and a `Plot`, how to `Filling` between them. For example, the `ParametricPlot` is $(\cos^2(x)+x, x-\sin(x))$, the `Plot` is $y=x$, and the plot range is $(0,1)$.

Comment: Please try to write down the code for the parametric plot and the plot. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
p1[x_] := {Cos@x^2 + x, x - Sin@x}; 

Plot[{x, p1[t][[2]] /. FindRoot[p1[t][[1]] == x, {t, 1}]}, {x, 0, 5}, 
     Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or perhaps better:

```
p = {Cos@#^2 + # &, # - Sin@# &};
Plot[{x, p[[2]]@InverseFunction[p[[1]]]@x}, {x, 0, 5}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

You can post-process the output of `ParametricPlot` to change lines into a polygon:

```
pplt = ParametricPlot[{{x , x}, {Cos[x]^2 + x, x - Sin@x}}, {x, 0, 5}];

coords = Cases[Normal[pplt], {dir___, Line[x_]} :> x, Infinity];
Graphics[{{Red, Thick, Line @ #, Blue, Line @ #2, LightBlue,
  Polygon[Join[#, Reverse @ #2]]} & @@ coords}, 
 Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1 / GoldenRatio]
```

[image]