# How can draw the inner region of the one -parameter function?

Tags: plotting, graphics, functions, regions, parametric-functions

```
fig1 = ParametricPlot[{(1 + r -12 r^2 + 4 r^3)/(2 r - 2 ), 
   Sqrt[(4 r^2)/(r - 1)^2 (r - r^2 (r - 3)^2)]}, {r, 2, 4}, 
  Axes -> True, Frame -> False, 
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[Yellow, Thick]}]

fig2 = ParametricPlot[{(1 + r - 12  r^2 + 4 r^3)/(
   2 r - 2 ), -Sqrt[(4 r^2)/(r - 1)^2 (r - r^2 (r - 3)^2)]}, {r, 2, 
   4}, Axes -> True, Frame -> False, 
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[Yellow, Thick]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-12, 12}, {-8, 8}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]

Show[fig1,fig2]
```

I dont draw of the inner region of this function (only one-parameter)? please help.

Comment: I think you just need `Show[fig1, fig2, PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: Hi, thank you your answer but this isnt satisfy. ı need like a regionplot.

Comment: This function doesnt transform to the cartesian format!!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: i found the answer of my question http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-fill-in-a-circle-made-by-parametricplot-with-one-solid-color
thenk you.

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-fill-in-a-circle-made-by-parametricplot-with-one-solid-color

Answer (score 6):

We "invent" the second parameter:

```
f[r_, n_] := {(1 + r - 12 r^2 + 4 r^3)/(2 r - 2), 
              n Sqrt[(4 r^2)/(r - 1)^2 (r - r^2 (r - 3)^2)]}

ParametricPlot[u f[r, 1] + (1 - u) f[r, -1], {r, 2, 4}, {u, 0, 1}, 
               Axes -> True, Frame -> False, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: How shall one beat 26 minutes. ;-(

Comment: @gwr That poses an interesting question! What is the statistic for the elapsed time until the first answer on this site?

Comment: Inventing second parameter is cheating! :)

Comment: @gwr http://i.stack.imgur.com/ji5LR.png

Comment: @gwr Query here http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematica/query/454758/histogram-minutes-until-first-answer#graph

Answer (score 4):

using `RegionPlot` ( this is awful slow.. )

```
region = ParametricRegion[{
    { (1 + r - 12 r^2 + 4 r^3)/(2 r - 2),
     z Sqrt[(4 r^2)/(r - 1)^2 (r - r^2 (r - 3)^2)]}, 
    2 < r < 4 && -1 < z < 1} , {r, z}];
RegionPlot[region, PlotRange -> {{-7, 7}, {-7, 7}}]
```

[image]

oddly if we supply the exact bounds on `r`:

```
 2 (1 + Sin[\[Pi]/18]) < r < 2 (1 + Cos[(2 \[Pi])/9])
```

its even slower..

Comment: Does anybody else get something like [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27062978/RegionPlot.pdf) from above code on Windows 10 (64 Bit) using Mathematica 10.4 or am I *unique*?

Comment: Maybe that ugly result also explains why it is not slow at all on my machine? ;-)

Comment: I checked it again, v10.1 takes a minute and a half.

Comment: Do you have an explanation for the result I am getting using your solution? (If you are on 10.1 then we might have an explanation for me getting a result in a blink -- which is wrong?)

Comment: With the exact bounds I am getting a circle (at last) in 0.15 secs.

Comment: @gwr, I get the same result as you, **10.4**

Comment: I have moved this issue to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28439407#28439407). It would be great if someone came up with an explanation as I am also getting *unknown option* error for `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"` for `RegionPlot` in 10.4.

Comment: I get [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/GblfC.png) with 10.4