# Interesting Progression of ParametricRegion: Bug?

Tags: bugs, computational-geometry, backslide

**Bug introduced In 10.1 or earlier and fixed 11.1**

---

Consider the following `ParametricRegion` from [an answer to this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/110738/how-can-draw-the-inner-region-of-the-one-parameter-function):

```
region = ParametricRegion[{{(1 + r - 12 r^2 + 4 r^3)/(2 r - 2), 
     z Sqrt[(4 r^2)/(r - 1)^2 (r - r^2 (r - 3)^2)]}, 
    2 < r < 4 && -1 < z < 1}, {r, z}];
```

Now let's discretize this region using various versions of *Mathematica* starting from **10.1**:

```
DiscretizeRegion[region]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Something is seriously wrong here, seems like a progression from **10.1** to **10.2**, then a serious (let's call it a bug) regression from **10.2** to **10.3**. **10.4** just gets the region wrong. The problem seems to be with `ParametricRegion` and how *Mathematica* handles them because I get similar wrong results with `RegionPlot` too. Can anyone confirm these?

Comment: Did your laptop installed all the **Mathematica** version like $10.1,10.2,10.3$ and $10.4$?

Comment: I found the same result (for v.10.4) on Windows and [Linux x86](http://i.imgur.com/72y0nf0.png)

Comment: Same with *v 10.3* on Linux.

Comment: @RunnyKine Shouldn't the B-word now be used without a question mark?

Comment: @gwr. You're probably right, but I can't think of a better way to rephrase it.

Comment: @RunnyKine I thought of having the usual Bug label (e.g. introduced in ...) at the top of the post. Will you report the issue(s) -- including the one on the other post -- to WRI?

Answer (score 3):

This bug is fixed in **11.1**:

```
region = ParametricRegion[{{(1 + r - 12 r^2 + 4 r^3)/(2 r - 2), 
     z Sqrt[(4 r^2)/(r - 1)^2 (r - r^2 (r - 3)^2)]}, 
    2 < r < 4 && -1 < z < 1}, {r, z}];

DiscretizeRegion[region]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]