# How to fill the heart curve with solid red color?

Tags: plotting, color, parametric-functions, filling

The parametric equation of the heart curve is from [this link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeartCurve.html)

$$\left\{\quad
\begin{array}{rcl}
 x&=&\cos {t} \cdot\sin {t} \cdot\ln \left| t\right| \\[10pt]
 y&=&\left| t\right| ^{0.3} \cdot\sqrt{\cos {t}} \\
\end{array}
\right.\quad t\in[-1,1]$$

Below the code visualizes the curve:

```
ParametricPlot[{Sin@t Cos@t Log@Abs@t,(Abs@t)^.3 Sqrt[Cos@t]}(*u,{u,0,1}*),{t,-1,1},PlotRange->All,PlotStyle->Red,MeshFunctions->{#3&  },MeshStyle->None]
```

[image]

I also want to fill the closed curve with some solid color, for instance, red. The following code:

```
ParametricPlot[{Sin@t Cos@t Log@Abs@t,(Abs@t)^.3 Sqrt[Cos@t]}u,{u,0,1},{t,-1,1},PlotRange->All,PlotStyle->Red,MeshFunctions->{#3&  },MeshStyle->None]
```

gives:

[image]

Let $O(0,0)$ be the coordinate system's origin, and $P(x,y)$ a moving point on the curve. Then it seems when there is intersection points between the segment connecting $O(0,0)$ and $P(x,y)$ and the closed curve, then there will be filling problem (filling color overflow).

When I move the curve to let $O$ inside the curve exactly problem will be solved relatively easier...(though still a little weird if the `PlotPoints` is still the default number)

[image]

Code:

```
ParametricPlot[{ Sin@t Cos@t Log@Abs@t,(Abs@t)^.3  Sqrt[Cos@t]-.71}u,{u,0,1},{t,-1,1},PlotRange->All,PlotStyle->Directive[Opacity[0,Red],Red],MeshShading->{Red, Red},MeshFunctions->{#3&},Mesh->Automatic,MeshStyle->Red,PlotPoints->200,Axes->None,Frame->None]
```

gives:

[image]

which is closer to the target but has the following disadvantages:

1. It is too slow;
2. There are white noise;

I wonder only for such a parameric equation without any coordinate transform, how can i fill it will solid color /pattern with options in `ParametricPlot`? I understand by approximating the closed curve with a polygon, things will also be easier, the key is whether it is possible to handle it with `ParametricPlot`'s `MeshFunction` related options?

Comment: I would say this is a dupe of [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10811). For your specific case: `ParametricPlot[{Sin@t Cos@t Log@Abs@t, (Abs@t)^.3 Sqrt[Cos@t]}, {t, -1, 1}, Axes -> None, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All] /. Line[l_List] :> {Directive[EdgeForm[Opacity[1/2, Black]], Opacity[1, Red]], Polygon[l]}`

Comment: thank you! I am interested in how to realize it with the `MeshFunctions` option in `ParametricPlot` itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
lst = Table[{Sin@t Cos@t Log@Abs@t, (Abs@t)^.3 Sqrt[Cos@t]}, {t, -1, 
1, 0.0001}];
```

and then

```
 ListLinePlot[lst, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All, 
 Filling -> Bottom, FillingStyle -> Red]
```

yielding the following

[image]

Have fun!