# Weird colors in Mathematica 10.2

Tags: plotting, color

I was trying to run a code that I saw on a answer for this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-fill-in-a-circle-made-by-parametricplot-with-one-solid-color)

The code is simply

```
ParametricPlot[{Cos[u], Sin[u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}] /.
  Line[l_List] :> {{Red, Polygon[l]}, {Black, Line[l]}}
```

And the result was supposed to be:

[image: filled circle]

However, when I run the same code in Mathematica 10.2 I get this result:
[image: filled circle bug]

I'm running exactly the same code, no extra global variables. Also, the color Red works perfectly fine in other situations. I've tried RGBColor[1,0,0] and the result is the same.

Similar issues happen with other colors too. Every color is "brighter".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is simple. Per default Mathematica reduces the opacity of the colors. Try the following:

```
ParametricPlot[{Cos[u], Sin[u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}] /. 
 Line[l_List] :> {{Red, Polygon[l]}, {Black, Line[l]}}

% /. _Opacity :> Opacity[1]
```

If you look at the `InputForm` of your graphics, you will notice a

```
FaceForm[Opacity[0.3]]
```

call right in the front. With this knowledge, you can simply fix it by calling:

```
ParametricPlot[{Cos[u], Sin[u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[1]] /. 
 Line[l_List] :> {{Red, Polygon[l]}, {Black, Line[l]}}
```

Answer (score 6):

I think using the 2nd argument of `Opacity` is a slightly simpler way to correct the problem than the methods given by halirutan, although those are perfectly fine.

```
ParametricPlot[{Cos[u], Sin[u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}] /. 
  Line[l_List] :> {{Opacity[1, Red], Polygon[l]}, {Black, Line[l]}}
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Explicitly setting the alpha channel is even simpler: `ParametricPlot[{Cos[u], Sin[u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}] /. Line[l_List] :> {{RGBColor[1, 0, 0, 1], Polygon[l]}, {Black, Line[l]}}`.